# Would like to get rid of new bar along the bottom of screen that shows active apps and workspaces

Tags: gnome, themes

I just installed ubuntu 13.04 Gnome Desktop, then upgraded to 13.10 and added a shell extension to use custom themes. I played around with installing themes, and now I have a bar across the top of the screen (which was there all along, and which I can find the settings for) and a bar along the bottom  - showing active apps and workspaces - that was not there before. I can't seem to get rid of it or find any settings for it - it's not the gnome bottom taskbar, that one's turned off (and appears under this one if I turn it on). I would gladly post a screenshot but apparently I don't rate.

Answer (score 1):

**Alt+Super+Right click** on any Gnome panel to get its properties or delete it.

**Alt+hold Left click**, to drag pannel to another place.

I think in theory it should be Alt-right click to get to the panel peoperties, but I think compiz now swallows this on default settings for something else.

Comment: Thanks, but neither action does anything with this panel, or actually, the top panel either. I started looking at compizConfig but was afraid I'd screw things up even further...

Answer (score -1):

(Sheepish!)

I logged out from Gnome classic and logged back in again straight up Gnome and the bar is gone. Thanks anyway.